# Which infectious disease would increase global life expectancy the most if eradicated

Tags: epidemiology, vaccination, lifespan, infectious-diseases

In the 1700s it was estimated, by Daniel Bernoulli, that wiping out smallpox would increase global life expectancy by over three years. If we could wipe out one infectious disease today, which would produce the largest increase in *global* life expectancy and by how much would life expectancy change?